# Rx Observable onCompleted called after disposed

Tags: android, rx-java2

I`m using RxJava2 in my android app. I have an `Observable` that, when created, is added to a `CompositeDisposable`. This `Observable` is retrieving data from some APIs and it can take pretty long to finish.

When I`m leaving the page while downloading, in `onPause`, I`m disposing this `CompositeDisposable`, but sometimes the `Observable``s `onComplete` is still called.

How can that happen?

Comment: I did do that, the onComplete is called after the observable is disposed

Comment: Try `onTerminateDetach` befure the `subscribe()` and see if it still happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in Doc,`onTerminateDetach` nulls out references to the upstream producer and downstream.

for example

```
mDisposable.add(
            apiClient.apiCallSomeAPI()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .concatMap(this::responseObservable)           
                    .toList()
                    .onTerminateDetach() // this is important, exactly before subscribe
                    .doOnSuccess(this::realmBulkOperation)
                    .subscribe(this::handleResult, this::handleError)
    );
```